# ctime_r failed in docker

Tags: c, ctime

I have a app in docker, which is multi-thread. And my code to transfer time is as below.

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
char buf[256] = {0};
char filename[64] = {0};
long timestamp;
char status[16] = {0};
char tbuf[26] = {0};


fp = popen(cmd, "r");
if (fp) {
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %s", filename, &timestamp, status) != EOF) {
        char *ts = ctime_r(&timestamp, tbuf);
        if (ts) {
            ts[strlen(ts)-1] = '\0';
            sprintf(buf, "%-32s%-32s%-8s", filename, ts, status);
        } else {
            sprintf(buf, "%-32s%-32s%-8s", filename, "Miss", status);
        }
    }
    pclose(fp);
}
```

But the content of tbuf is as "Sat Oct 29 21:37:05 44614", and the ts is NULL.

I think the timestamp is a valid value. But why it failed?

Comment: Does `ctime_r()` expect a `long *` or something else?  See [ref](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime_r).  If compiler warnings are not fully enabled, you are wasting your valuable time.

Comment: _"If compiler warnings are not fully enabled, you are wasting your valuable time."_ Amen.

Comment: Post a [mcve] including include files, `main()`, how `1535686785` was read from a file, file contents  and how the "Sat Oct 29 21:37:05 44614" was determined (printed).  This aids in arriving at a rapid solution.

Comment: @chux It's not the error of ctime_r, but the fscanf. I use %d to read the timestamp, so just the low bit of timestamp has been filled. I just set timestamp to 0, everything is ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it failed?

OP later added code and reported ["error of ... fscanf"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108207/ctime-r-failed-in-docker?noredirect=1#comment91167557_52108207).

With warnings well enabled, my compiler warned also.

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 4 has type 'long int *'

---

To read `time_t` from a text file is tricky.  The range, epoch, data type attributes are all in play.  Further as textualized data in a file, the attributes may differ from the system that wrote it.  Note there is no `fscanf()` specifier for `time_t`.

For now, let us make the assumption that the textual time stamp is simply numeric and corresponds to an integer `time_t`, even though we do not know the integer type specifics.  More advanced techniques do not require these assumptions.

Read the time stamp using the widest signed type available like `intmax_t` (or `long` on pre-C99 systems).  Some range checking is worth the effort.  I'd also recommend to write `time_t` using the same wide type.

Note: better to compare `fscanf()` return value to the one expected value (3) rather than against only one of the various unexpected values (EOF, 0, 1, 2).  Use width limits for string input.

```
char filename[64] = {0};
char status[16] = {0};
// long timestamp;

// while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %s", filename, &timestamp, status) != EOF) {
intmax_t timestamp_big;   
while (fscanf(fp, "%63s %jd %15s", filename, &timestamp_big, status) == 3) {
  time_t timestamp = (time_t) timestamp_big;
  if (timestamp != timestamp_big) Handle_OutOfRangeError();
  ...
```

`long timestamp` is prone to the [Y2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).